# Windows config survey - How to get the connected SSID and security mode

Tags: windows, wifi

We need to inventory a lot of WinXX machines, many of them outside our premises and using wifi networks other than our own. We already found straightforward ways to retrieve all the information we want except the connected wifi SSID and security mode (WEP/WPA/WPA2) ...

After googling for a while, I can't find a way working in an inhomogeneous environment.

Relevant environment data:

1. The machines may run any Win version from WinXP SP3 onwards
2. We don't have access to the APs (in many circumstances they are provided to a second company by a third party :(  ), but we can suppose that all the SSIDs are being broadcasted
3. We can run programs in the machines under administrator privileges.
4. We can't tell the users to write down their configs :)
5. Some of the machines have their wifi connections managed by windows while others could be under any hardware-specific manager like [Intel's Pro/Set](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/cs-008168.htm?wapkw=intel%20proset%2Fwireless%20software), but we don't have reliable data about this

Any app/code/hint pointer can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the Win32 native WiFi API, available since Windows XP SP3. I suppose that the hardware-specific connection managers should not prevent this API from correctly working, although it would be something to verify...

There is a nice example of how to retrieve information about the WiFi profiles here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/577445/Querying-Wireless-Settings-and-Decrypting-Wireless.

On later versions of Windows, another possibility is to execute the `netsh wlan show interfaces` command and parse its output (although this might be tricky if you have to deal with machines having the OS installed in different languages), but unfortunately net `wlan` context is not supported by `netsh` on Windows XP. If you're looking for a command-line solution on Windows XP, you can try to look at the [`wlan.exe` tool available from Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/how-capture-and-deploy-wlan-profiles).

Comment: Yep. I am aware of the `netsh` command. But it doesn't support `wlan` under XP. A shame.

Comment: Also, I think the Symantec tool needs WZC running, and I can't be sure of that (although I may try starting it, I prefer a stand-alone solution)

Comment: Yes it seems to need the WZC service. It's possibly the Windows WiFi API itself that needs this service? Perhaps you might start it before using the tool (just issue a `net start WZCSVC` as administrator, of course if the service has been disabled you would have to enable it beforehand, e.g., by using the `sc` tool).

Comment: Well, I'm right now trying to compile some sample programs using the wifi API, so I will know if it requires the WZC service running soon. With so many potential things wreaking havoc in distributed and non-controlled installations I don't want to mess with the machines configs for _just_ an inventory!